# How can I fix Firefox and Google Chrome both crashing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS12 laptop with an external monitor connected via USB/HDMI adapter. Firefox came preinstalled. I also installed Google Chrome from Snapd. I synced up both browsers with my logging into my accounts. For the first few days, both browsers worked very well. Then, one day, Google Chrome crashed Ubuntu after having played YouTube videos for a few hours.I had to turn the computer off at the power button as no less radical mode of recovery would recover the OS. From then on, the Chrome browser crashed more and more often, in the end even when not playing video, only simply by clicking around on websites. In the meantime, Firefox still worked okay. Then I played YouTube videos on Firefox. The same happened there: At first there were no problems, then Firefox became more and more shaky, exactly as it happened with the Chrome browser. I disabled hardware axcelleration on both browsers but that did not help. I ran a file cleaner and uninstalled both browsers, reinstalled Firefox and at least I can post this now. I researched similar posts on AskUbuntu.com but nothing there helped me in the right direction. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. How much memory is installed? 2. Run memtest64 to confirm memory is ok. 3. Run System Monitor and check the memory usage when the problem starts up. Also, I'm wondering why you are using Chrome instead of Chromium (deb version, not snap).

Comment: The laptop has 8GB memory installed. memtest64 came back clean. I can't get into System Monitor as the problem comes on so quickly that the machine is already frozen up before I can get there. I installed Chrome mainly because I sync with my Google Chrome account on other machines.

Comment: You can't run System Monitor, even before running a browser? Maybe you can see something there.

Comment: I have cleaned my OS, discarded of useless browser plugins and since have not experienced any more crashes. System Monitor shows the 4 CPUs running between 40 to 50% during YouTube videos. I have not had a freeze since. I consider this solved for now. I don't know what happened but cleaning and reinstalling browsers helped. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I have a similar issue. with 16 GB of RAM chrome debug says core dump. segment falts